# XPath: Get text that contains Obama but not Romney

Tags: xpath

I am quite new to XPath so bear with me. I have a XPath expression

`'.//*[contains(.,"Obama")]/text()'`

that gets me the text that contains "Obama". However, I haven't been able to figure out how to add

`and [not(contains(., "Romney"))]` to the expression without getting a syntax error. How is it done? Help much appriciated!

Comment: Is it a real IT question, or your are just flaming about US elections ?

Comment: I'm just a French Frog, but `Romney` seems a wrong expression...

Comment: I suggest you choose different strings to search before this question gets closed.

Comment: Well actually it's a real world example as I am trying it on a newspaper website covering the elections :)

Comment: http://news.google.com/ and Romney is up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
.//*[contains(.,"Obama") and not(contains(.,"Romney"))]/text()
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     './/*[contains(.,"Obama") and not(contains(.,"Romney"))]/text()'/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<election>
 <choice>Maybe  Obama</choice>
 <choice>Maybe Romney</choice>
</election>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected node is copied to the output:**

```
Maybe  Obama
```

**Do note**:

```
SomeExpression[x][y]
```

is not always equivalent to:

```
SomeExpression[x and y]
```

Therefore, it is recommended the latter -- not the former, as specified in the answer by @ChrisGerken.

**Here is a concrete example**:

**Let's have this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**and these two XPath expressions**:

```
/*/*[. mod 3 = 0 and position() = 3]
```

**and**

```
/*/*[. mod 3 = 0][position() = 3]
```

**The first expression selects**:

```
<num>03</num>
```

**However, the second expression selects**:

```
<num>09</num>
```

**And here is a complete XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*[. mod 3 = 0 and position() = 3]"/>
     ================
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*[. mod 3 = 0][position() = 3]"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the results of these evaluations are copied to the output:**

```
<num>03</num>
================
<num>09</num>
```

**Explanation**:

`position()` is a *context-sensitive` function and typically produces different results when used in the k-th and in the m-th predicate, where k != m

Comment: Can you elaborate about the difference from the ansewer provided by Chirs Gerken, or is the difference only a synactic one?

Comment: @root, See my updated answer for an example where the recommended by Chris Gerken expression may produce unwanted results.

Comment: thank you for the in depth explanation, it was more than i hoped to find.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
'.//*[contains(.,"Obama")][not(contains(.,"Romney"))]/text()'
```

You can put as many predicates as you like one after another:

```
[a][b][c]
```

Comment: this gets "Obama diagnoses rival with 'Romnesia'", but otherwise it works great, thanks.

Comment: but that's what you asked for, right?  "Romnesia" is not an exact match with Romney. And I do wish you'd used different names just for discussion purposes.  These particular strings bring out quite a bit of emotion. :)

Comment: just joking about the "Romnesia" and hey who say's XPath should be unemotional. Thanks again for your help, your answer cleared things up for me.

Comment: i am sorry, but i think i have to change the accepted answer, as @Dimitre Novatchev has added some insights explaining the differences of these two solutions. i hope you don't mind.